# Update cURL in wampserver

Tags: php, curl, wampserver

I have wampserver 2.2E in my windows system which includes below version:

```
PHP: 5.3.13
Apache: 2.2.22
cURL: 7.24
```

I have to access some file of sharepoint. When I access that file, I got below error:

```
HTTP/1/1 401: unauthorised
```

When I searched, I found that upgrading newer version of cURL can fix this issue. But, how to upgrade this extension? Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download newer PHP version and get the php_curl.dll from the ext folder and replace it (after taking backup) http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Do I need to change anything in php.ini file?

Comment: If it's the same name in the same directory? No, just restart the wamp/apache server.