# Update cURL in wamp

Tags: curl, wamp, libcurl, twilio

Can I get more info on upgrading the cURL in the WAMP server. I have seen [Update cURL in wampserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323017/update-curl-in-wampserver) but can some one give more explanation. I have cURL 7.36.0 but need 7.41 for TWILIO.

1. which cURL should I download?
2. How to update the cURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step by Step

**Step 1**

Download for 32-bit: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
Download for 64-bit: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x64.zip

**Step 2**

Extract File (Overwrite file - It is a good idea to keep a backup of the file in case something fails):
`/etx/php_curl.dll` into `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\`

**NOTE:** your `phpx.x.x` folder might be different (depends on your php version)

**Step 3**

Restart Apache from WAMP Control Panel

**Update**

Php archived the previous links. Please, find the links here:

http://museum.php.net/php5/

Comment: no problem let me know. Make sure to backup the file before you overwrite it. In case something happens you can reverse the change

Comment: So i overwrite the php_curl.dll From php-5.6.7 into the old php folder? and still keep the old php

Comment: i get a orange light after restart has been made. i have added the new php_curl.dll into the old php folder.

Comment: Also, what PHP version  do you have?

Comment: 5.5.12 is my php version and apache is 2.4.9

Comment: [23-Mar-2015 23:03:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @cocominion that is not even the library that we overwrite. However, I think the `dll` is also in the downloaded zip file. Extract it too.

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119182,119190#msg-119190 is a good website for help

Comment: Above  links are broken, no php download available there