# update CURL in PHP WAMP windows

Tags: php, curl, wamp, libcurl

i encountered an issue and can't seem to be able to solve it.

i downloaded the cURL from http://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/

and mapped my sys path to it which runs at 7.49.1 but my PHP is still running 7.42.1

How can i map or point the latest CURL to my php?

any pointer are greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Do you really mean you run command-line version of the curl utility from PHP (e.g using `system()`) as opposed to using the PHP extension? If so, what does your PHP code look like? How exactly did you "map my sys path to it"?

Comment: curl's php extension != curls binary for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing as downloading vanilla cURL and binding it with PHP. You need [PHP](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/) version of cURL.

> ### Step by Step
>
> **Step 1**
>
> Download for 32-bit:
>   http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
>   Download for 64-bit:
>   http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x64.zip
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Extract File (Overwrite file - It is a good idea to keep a backup of
>   the file in case something fails): `/etx/php_curl.dll` into
>   `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\`
>
> **NOTE:** your `phpx.x.x` folder might be different (depends on your php version)
>
> **Step 3**
>
> Restart Apache from WAMP Control Panel

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222016/1194797)

Comment: Curl or rather the `php_curl.dll` comes with PHP, all you need to do is activate the extension in the CORRECT `php.ini` file. There are 2, one in the `\apache\bin` folder used by PHP under Apache and one in the `\php` folder used by the PHP CLI

Comment: If you are using a `https` domain then also activate the `php_openssl` extension